# database query in c#

Tags: c#, database

I am just facing a problem to access the data which is given by the user 
but if i am specifying the query directly it is running fine

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string v = (enterId.Text);
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM professor WHERE branch=***"+ v +"***", cn);
        sda.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader dr = sda.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            v = dr[0].ToString();
            selectName.Items.Add(v);
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

        cn.Close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: _" facing a problem"_ would you mind telling us the problem?

Comment: Don't use one variable for two different purposes. `v` is used as parameter for `branch`(always use sql parameters instead of string concatenation) and also for the selected `name` later. It doesn't hurt to introduce a new: `string name = dr.GetString(0)`

Comment: Attention please: *SQL injection* is coming. Take a look for [SqlParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx).

Comment: Hi, my name is *'); drop table professor;'*.

Comment: Strange name @Oliver

Comment: ya but if we use directly the query then it will just Increases the code length

Answer (score 2):

you need to use quotes:

```
"SELECT name FROM professor WHERE branch='***"+ v +"***'"
```

However you MUST use parameters and not concatenate strings in your query.